# recursive game plan function

Tags: java, recursion

I want to write a simple recursive function for a game plan in java.
I have 2^k teams and want an output like this (e.g. 4 teams):

```
(team)(day1)(day2)(day3)
  1     2     3     4
  2     1     4     3
  3     4     1     2
  4     3     2     1
```

My idea was to call the function recursive with half of its original size, but I can't figure out how to code it properly. If called with n/2, the output has to go into the upper left corner of the plan, the output PLUS n/2 has to go to the lower left corner and the rest is symmetric to the center.

Thanks

**My code so far**

```
public void plan(int size) { 
      if(size==2){} 
      else{} 
}
```

Comment: What's your specific question?

Comment: i can't figure out what to put into the recursive function. i got this far atm

public void plan(int size){
if(size==2){}
else{}
}

Comment: This looks like Tabular Data. Usually recursion is good for tree structures. Iteration is usually the weapon of choice when displaying data like this..

Comment: no. you need to explain the problem! what is the problem you are trying to solve

Comment: console output is written line by line. You won't be able to write something at the end of a line that has already been written. Recursion is clearly not the right tool. Use a loop.

Comment: Sounds like you need a matrix.

Comment: I can't figure out from the example what you want if there are 8 teams. Please be specific.

Answer (score 0):

make a Set for each day (unique)

then use n(max number)

itterate a loop n times and each itteration
newRandomNumber % n (fetch a random number a limit it to 0 to (n-1)

now add the (generatedValue+1) to the set
if it already exists (do check ) then increment the value till its new value then add to set

note: i dont get ur symetric requirement

Comment: about the symmetric stuff: 
for 8 days you would at first do (if attempted recursive) the first day, so it is:
12
21
afterwards until day 3:
1234
2143
3412
4321
and then you just have to add n/2 (4 here) to each value for the lower left corner. this one is the same as the upper right corner and the lower right corner is the same as the upper left one

Comment: a bigger sample data/example may help

Comment: for 8 teams
12345678
21436587
34127856
43218765
56781234
65872143
78563412
87654321
the upper left 4x4 corner is the same as the lower right one, same for up right and low left